# django approve or reject for everyone field in object

Tags: django, django-models

I am looking for a package or hints on how to track each field and the ability to accept or reject editing
i using Django 1.11 and python3
Package like:
django_monitor not working
django_approve not working

Comment: I didn't get your question, can you explain in more details?

Comment: of course, I want to create a model with 5 fields, which can be added by the user but must be accepted by the moderator or if there is a range, np 2 adds automatically and adds points for adding, and the same situation with editing, only wants to be able to edit the individual field. eg someone changes the title, it has to be accepted if there are points added (all changes to be displayed in the view in order to accept them) and if they are rejected, to keep the latest editions or to add them for 7 days

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [django-moderation](https://github.com/dominno/django-moderation) should fit you need. I haven't used it personally, but the [docs](http://django-moderation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) mention that it's possible to have changes displayed only after a moderator accepts them, and there is also an option ([keep_history](http://django-moderation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_options.html#genericmoderator-options)) to maintain the history of the changes made to a model.

Comment: How is it not working for you? How have you set it up?

Comment: Ok, right now work, idk why but is work, i will be change and tell you is good :) but thanks so much :)